# How to delete a row when a button is clicked inside a DataGrid column?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have a data table with users and I want to make a delete button work on the rows, but it seems that it cannot be done by reactish means.

The DataGrid is used like this:

```
<DataGrid
  rows={users}
  columns={columns}
  pageSize={5}
  checkboxSelection
/>
```

I have a column with custom renderCell function that shows some action buttons. The column definition is this:

```
{
  field: "actions",
  headerName: "",
  width: 120,
  type: "",
  sortable: false,
  renderCell: (
    params: GridCellParams
  ): React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>> => {
    return (
      <UserRowActions
        userId={params.getValue(params.id, "id")?.toString()!}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The params object offers a few properties but I do not know how to do something like this: delete the row on which a button was clicked, a button that is defined in the `UserRowActions` component.

I would also like to find whether it is not possible to do this using the MUI DataGrid component as it is today.

I don't know what to do since the API does not look reactish to me right now.

I use:

```json
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.1",
"@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.30",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) specially for the data grid action buttons:

```
export const DataGridContext = React.createContext<{ deleteUser?: (uid: string) => void }>({});

// ...

const { data: users, isLoading, isError } = useGetUsersQuery();

const [usersRows, setUsersRows] = useState<IUser[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof users !== 'undefined') {
    setUsersRows(users);
  }
}, [users]);

<DataGridContext.Provider value={{ deleteUser: (uid: string) => {
  const newRows = [...usersRows];
  const idx = newRows.findIndex(u => u.id === uid);

  if (idx > -1) {
    newRows.splice(idx, 1);
    setUsersRows(newRows);
  }
}}}>
  <DataGrid
    rows={usersRows} // ...
  />
</DataGridContext.Provider>

// In the UserRowActions component:

const dataGrid = useContext(DataGridContext);

// ...

dataGrid.deleteUser!(userId);
```